# MySQL Workbench failed to connect to my RDS database : Unable to connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-connection, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am new to RDS, this is the first time i'm trying to connect MySQL Workbench to a remote DBMS so i'm not sure where is the problem.

- **What i want to do :** connect workbench to rds so i can add manually data to my database ( i would prefer to do it with a GUI )
  PS :
- **Useful informations :** The RDS database was created by Elastic Beanstalk from a jar file (spring boot) i uploaded.
- **What is the problem :** workbench can't connect to rds and tells me "unable to connect to localhost" when it is clearly a remote server.
  [The error message returned after a test connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6vDG.png)
- **What i tried to fix the issue :**

  - Check the connection informations : all of them are correct : i am using TCP/IP connection
  - Check the accessibility : the server is public
  - Edit Inbound rules : the server is accepting all incoming requests
  - Try other GUI : DBeaver faailed with this error : " Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
    received any packets from the server. " : unknown host
- **What i want to know** :

  - What can cause this issue ? Why is Workbench refering to my server as localhost when it is not ? Is there any logging system for RDS/Workbench i can use for further investigations ?
  - Is there any alternatives for my need ?

**Thank you for your help !**

Comment: amazon has a really good tutorial for mysql workbench, try to follow the steos and tell which doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just connected to my RDS instance using MySQL workbench.

[image]

Your issue sounds like an inbound rule issue. To rule that out, ***double check*** your rule that lets all traffic in. Once you determine that is the cause, you can change it.

Also, make sure that you specify the endpoint in your login screen and have correctly set the password and user name.